# Back vs. Up - Intended behavior

Tags: android, navigation, back

The navigation design guide explains:

> When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of the current screen, pressing the Back button has the same result as pressing an Up button—this is a common occurrence.
> [up vs back - navigation guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph)

I have a MainActivity A which opens another activity B when touching a navigation entry in the NavigationDrawer. Activity A is set to be the parent of activity B in the AndroidManifest: `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"`

I followed this [android documentaion](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation) to add up navigation to activity B. It shows how to implement `onOptionsItemSelected` in activity B:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
when (item.itemId) {
    android.R.id.home -> {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)
        return true
    }
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
```

}

When I press back from Activity B the state of Activity A was saved and the NavigationDrawer is opened. If I use the up navigation though, `onCreate()`of activity A is called and it lost its state (the drawer is closed etc.).

This is not the quoted "same result".

When I replace the `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` with a simple `finish()` it has the same behavior as pressing back - the state of activity A is kept.

Naturally I would prefer the way using finish. So what is the intended behavior? Do the guides contradict each other or am missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an unfortunate reality that Google leaves documentation up for longer than it is relevant, and will even post two different pieces of documentation that directly contradict each other.

In the case of the Up button, your link says

> The Up button appears in the app bar and is used to navigate within an app based on the hierarchical relationships between screens. [...]
>
> The Back button appears in the system navigation bar and is used to navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.

However, there is also [this article](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-principles), which says

> When the system Back button would not exit your app, such as when you are on your own task and not on the start destination, the Up button should function identically to the system Back button.

So... which one should you trust?

I assert that you should trust the second one. The first one was posted years ago; I don't know its exact age, but you can tell that it's old because the screenshots all use the Holo theme. The second one, on the other hand, is part of Android's Architecture Components, so is significantly newer. In general, I'd go with the newest piece of documentation.

Additionally, I think that Google was *wrong* to say for all these years that the Up button should work differently from the Back button. As someone who spent a lot of time thinking about navigation in my app, I see where they were coming from, but real-world users always get confused when Up did something "different".

So I'd go ahead and just `finish()` your activity when the user presses the Up button, and not worry about those two articles you found.

Comment: I came across here to find a solution to exactly those 2 conflicting documentations. I love the concept of "back vs up" and it is in fact a different thing which should behave different but (as said) "real world" users don't understand it and therefore expect the same result. So it seems that Google will ditch the up-button and (when kept instead of removed) let it behave just as the back-button (which is sad and duplicated).

Answer (score 0):

I think the change of policy to suggest consistency between the up icon and the system back button is a good idea. However the advice that you should:
"navigate in reverse-chronological order through the history of screens"
Is too crude, or at least should be clarified what they mean by "screen".
eg. When you have a bottom nav bar, the back button / up icon should take you back up the hierarchy within your tab section before jumping to the section previously visited. And you should preserve the previous state when revisiting a tab section (which may be drilled down into a lower level screen).